# Selecting and grouping from two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, union

I have two tables... one that contains daily values of various indexes on the stock market, ie, FTSE100, NASDAQ, etc. The columns and some sample data:

```
id, index_name, date,      value
1,  FTSE100,    03/03/01,  8998.90
```

The other table contains stock prices for individual stocks. The columns are:

```
id, stock_name, date,       value
1,  fb,         02/03/01,   45
2,  twtr,       01/01/01,   398.00
3,  twtr,       02/03/01,   399.50
```

I need to (ideally in SQL only) query any combination of stocks and indexes, for example, fb, twtr, ftse100 and show it the following output:

```
 Date,      fb,     twtr,     ftse100
 01/01/01,  null,   398.00,   null
 02/03/01,  45,     399.50,   null
 03/03/01,  null,   null,     8998.90
```

Could anyone help on how to do this reasonably efficiently? Thank you.

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` per item in your 'combination of stocks and indexes' may be needed, possibly based on a simple sequential date table if I read correctly that entries may not exist.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: He's asking how to PIVOT the UNION of tblIndex and tblStock.

Comment: I've added some same data that hopefully explains better the output I need and what I've got to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be usefull for your needs:

```
SELECT date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name='fb' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS fb,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name='twtr' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS twtr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name='FTSE100' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS ftse100
  FROM (SELECT date, index_name AS name, value FROM index_table
        UNION
        SELECT date, stock_name AS name, value FROM stock_table)
        AS derivedtable
 GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Needs "AS derivedtable" after the FROM(). But that did it, thanks.